# I am trying to update existing excel worksheet data but it gives me error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: typescript, protractor, exceljs

I need to download a excel template, fill the data and upload back. I am using exceljs. reading file data, updating and then trying to save workbook gives error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined".

```js
await wb.xlsx.readFile(filename).then(async()=>{          
            
            let Code:number, Active :number ;
            console.log("Workbook is: "+wb);
            let workSheet:excel.Worksheet = wb.getWorksheet("Sheet1"); //I can't create new worksheet i have to update existing worksheet's cell values.
            console.log("Worksheet is: "+workSheet);
            
            workSheet.getRow(7).eachCell(function(cell, colNumber){
                console.log('Cell ' + colNumber + ' = ' + cell.value);
                switch(cell.value)
                {
                    case "Code":{
                        Code = colNumber;
                        break;       

                    }
                    case"Active":{
                        Active = colNumber;
                        break;
                    }
                }            

            });
            await browser.sleep(6000);
            console.log(workSheet.getRow(8).getCell(Code).value + "Active : "+
            workSheet.getRow(8).getCell(Active).type.toString());
            var row =workSheet.getRow(8);
            row.getCell(8).value= 'Y';
            
           
           return wb.xlsx.writeFile(filename);
            
        });
```

Comment: You need to make sure `workSheet.getRow(8).getCell(Active).type` is not `undefined`, because that appears to be what's happening now.

Comment: workSheet.getRow(8).getCell(Active).type prints 3. how to set cell type which accepts string or any (Font general type)value.

Comment: I tried to pint cell value after setting it to "y" at row.getCell(8).value= 'Y'; the value is printed correctly. Error is thrown at last line "return wb.xlsx.writeFile(filename); "